# Error in Angular app running on .NET Core in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, angular-cli, azure-service-fabric

I have created a new service fabric application, added a stateless .NET Core service (.NET Core 2.1) and selected the angular template. It builds fine and all looks OK however when I run it I get this error:

[image]

`Startup.cs` contains a line `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");` which is only used in development, if I remove this line then I no longer get this error but it doesn't pick up any of my changes to code.

I have tried updating my npm, node, angular cli versions, updating the project to angular 7 (it is 5 by default) with no luck.

If I run `ng serve` directly in the ClientApp folder it runs OK so the issue seems to be to do with it being hosted in .NET Core or SF.

It seems it could be something to do with the SF service not having permissions to create/edit files/folders under system32?

Comment: Can you manually create the folder `c:\\windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\appdata\\roaming\\npm` on the server? Copy the `npm` folder from your own profile: `c:\\users\\<you>\\appdata\\roaming\\npm`. You're probably right, because its in dev configuration, its trying to create a folder because it doesn't already exist using the account that the service is running under. Alternatively, try an elevated account, which does have permissions

Comment: @pixelbits I did try manually creating the npm folder, I then got basically the same error but complaining that it already existed! I didn't think to try copying mine so I will give that a shot. My user account is an admin, is there a way to run SF with elevated permissions?

Comment: not sure about SF, but you will need to know the service account (are you running under IIS, then its the AppPool identity?) so you can grant it the right permissions to the folder

Comment: @pixelbits I think you got me on the right track, found a solution now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected it was to do with SF not having permission to modify that folder. Service fabric runs under the user `NETWORK SERVICE`.

I found 2 ways to fix it:

**1. Manually grant permission to NETWORK SERVICE**

I navigated to `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming` and edited the permissions in that folder to give the user `NETWORK SERVICE` permissions to read/write

**2. Edit ApplicationManifest.xml to give SF admin permissions**

By adding

```
<Principals>
  <Users>
    <User Name="LocalAdmin" AccountType="NetworkService">
      <MemberOf>
        <SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />
      </MemberOf>
    </User>
  </Users>
</Principals>
<Policies>
  <DefaultRunAsPolicy UserRef="LocalAdmin" />
</Policies>
```

Either of these seems to make it work. The best part is all it eventually did is create an empty `npm` folder there.

Comment: Why don't you run as static files instead? Or maybe you could host a NodeJs as guest executable!